# how to pass the data while navigating to other component

Tags: angular, routes

I need to navigate to Comp B from Comp A on click of button, while navigating I wanted to pass the employee number data to the Comp B. I don't want query string URL format due to security issue(should not be like app/structure/profile/12345)

how to navigate the Comp B by passing data.

Comp A html code:

```
<button class="btn btn-outline-primary " routerLink="/structure/profile">View profile</button>
```

What I have tried is:

```
<button class="btn btn-outline-primary " (click)="OpenTheProfile(object.Emp_no)">View profile</button>
```

```
 OpenProfile(emp_no){
  this.router.navigate(['/structure/profile'],{ state: { example: 'emp_no' } });
```

but this data will get vanish after page refresh, I want to retain the data, so how to achieve this in Angular

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want data to be there after page refresh, you should use `localStorage` to save it.

```
OpenProfile(emp_no) {
      localStorage.setItem('emp_no', emp_no);
      this.router.navigate(['/structure/profile']);
    }
```

Then in Comp B get the value from localStorage

```
ngOnInit() {
      const empNo = localStorage.getItem('emp_no');
    }
```

Comment: I have tried with the localstorage, it is working.. Thank you Okan Aslankan

Comment: if it's working for you can you please mark as right answer

Comment: already done, but due to reputation issue, vote will be not be displayed publicly.

Answer (score 1):

You can configure data to be sent at the definition of the routes:

```js
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'structure/profile'
    data: { example: 'emp_no' },
    component: ProfileComponent
  }
]
```

When navigated to 'structure/profile' this data gets sent and you can subscribe at the ProfileComponent:

```js
this.route.data.subscribe(data => {
  this.example = data['example'];
});
```

If it is dynamic data then you have to create a resolver and for example fetch the data with some service call:

```
@Injectable()
export class ExampleResolver implements Resolve<ExampleData> {
  constructor(private exampleService: ExampleService, private router: Router) {}

  resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): Observable<ExampleData> {
    return  this.exampleService.getExampleData();
  }       
}
```

and again you have to subscribe to `this.route.data` at the ProfileComponent.

Comment: I will try resolver concept and will post back here the result. Thank you BLD